Android WebRtc with mediaProjection will be stutter/lag when move the app to background
My app work on Android TV, It seems all right when the app is in front.
I created virtualDisplay as below
mp.createVirtualDisplay("name", width, height, 300, DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR, new Surface(surfaceTextureHelper.getSurfaceTexture()), null,null);

I found OnFrameAvailable of SurfaceTexture didn't call when it's in background. How to force refresh frames maybe the point.
